# JavaScript Form Fields Repeated in Pop-Up

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a website for class, just HTML and CSS, but trying to play around with JavaScript on my own.  At this point, I have a form that I want all of the fields to be repeated back to the user via a pop-up before sending onward.  I don't have anything towards actually sending the information further at this point, just trying to get the actual pop-up done, but for the life of me I don't seem to be able to get anywhere.
As far as code:

```
    <form name="submitForm" id="submitForm" method="post" action="#">
    <textarea style="width: 145px" name="Name" id="nameTA" placeholder="Your name"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea style="width: 145px" name="Contact Information" id="contactInfoTA" placeholder="Your contact information"></textarea><br/>
    <textarea name="Message" style="height: 200px; width: 145px" id="messageTA" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitButton" onsubmit="send();" value="Send Message"></input> <br/>
</form>
```

is the original form and the JS is:

```
function send() { 
var nameJS = document.getElementById('nameTA').textContent;
var contactJS = document.getElementById('contactInfoTA').textContent;
var messageJS = document.getElementById('messageTA').textContent;
if(nameJ === "" || contactJ === "" || messageJ === "")
{
    alert("Please fill out all fields.");
}
else
{
    alert(" Name: " + nameJS.value + " \n Contact Info: " + contactJS.value + " \n Message: " + messageJS.value + " \n Submitted!");
}
```

}

I've tried running this locally or on altervista, document.getElementById().value; .textContent; and I'm getting next to no information in the console and I am running out of ideas, so any help would be much appreciated - perhaps something to do with the onsubmit parameters, or action="#"?  Not sure....  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the onsubmit event on the form and not on the input button.

```
<form name="submitForm" id="submitForm" method="post" action="#" onsubmit="send();">
<textarea style="width: 145px" name="Name" id="nameTA" placeholder="Your name"></textarea><br/>
<textarea style="width: 145px" name="Contact Information" id="contactInfoTA" placeholder="Your contact information"></textarea><br/>
<textarea name="Message" style="height: 200px; width: 145px" id="messageTA" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitButton" value="Send Message"></input> <br/>
</form>
```

In your JS function inside the if condition you are specifying the variable names wrong. Also you are not getting the values of the input fields like so. You don't need the '.textContent'. The '.value' inside your else is already enough. Also this function is missing a closing curly bracket.
Else you don't want to check for equality in the if condition. This is what '===' does. Instead what you are trying to do is checking for the same value, which can be achieved with '=='. Anyhow this doesn't work either, because no input and an empty string are not the same. Instead you could check if the elements are even containing a value.

```
function send() { 
    var nameJS = document.getElementById('nameTA');
    var contactJS = document.getElementById('contactInfoTA');
    var messageJS = document.getElementById('messageTA');
    if(!nameJS.value || !contactJS.value || !messageJS.value) {
        alert("Please fill out all fields.");
    } else {
        alert(" Name: " + nameJS.value + " \n Contact Info: " + contactJS.value + " \n Message: " + messageJS.value + " \n Submitted!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright... still not working.  Playing around with alerts, looks like the JS is just not triggering one way or the other -- been using that in a separate send.js file rather than in the actual if statement.  Think what I'm going to do is scrap this... well, not really, still have to submit the HTML/CSS for class, but strip out the JS and work a proof-of-concept side-project.  It might have taken a while to realize I'm doing onsubmit in the wrong spot, but I have no idea how long it would have taken to realize the === wouldn't work on null entries - wasn't a consideration.  Thank you much ! :)

Comment: Just post some more code if you still want to stick to it and I will try to help. Everything's possible! Otherwise you could accept the answer. ;)

Comment: I'm playing around with the alerts, found something interesting.  The form is on a sidebar that is included with w3data.js and not the actual main page itself. Even just putting a <script>alert();</script> on this sidebar page, nothing is popping up, though if I load the sidebar page directly as it's own page, the alerts show, so it is some sort of interaction between the included page and w3data.js

Comment: As an edit to the last comment, somewhere in everything, I must have stopped wiping the browser caches -- a good night's sleep and suddenly things are magically working.  I wish I could say that was definitively it, but I know I was wiping caches constantly, just thinking I must have slacked there at the end because it's magically working now. :)